# URL rewrite Rule

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, php

URL rewrite Rule

my page works if the user is given URL like this

```
show.php?id=(15chars)
```

How to write rewrite rule that works on both cases

/show/(15chars)

show.php?id=(15chars)

I tried like this but it is redirecting /show/(15chars) to show.php?id=(15chars)

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/show/([a-zA-Z0-9]{15})$ http://site.com/show.php?id=$1
```

if user gives url like this means if he adds **&m=true** to the url

```
show/(15chars)&m=true
```

I have to redirect it to another page where html version will be available

```
html/show.php?id=(15chars)
```

Comment: Can you add some examples of what source addresses need to be re-written to what target addresses? Your question is very unclear as it stands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, that your problem we can divide to two rules:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/show/([a-zA-Z0-9]{15})&m=true$ http://site.com/html/show.php?id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^/show/([a-zA-Z0-9]{15})$ http://site.com/show.php?id=$1 [L]
```